# Jasonarray querying in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have been through most of the threads here regarding this question but no answer. I am using MySQL and need to query from a table in database. The data is nested, in a column named **info**, in a table called **auto** and looks like this:

```
[{"id":7,"values":[10,30]},
 {"id":8,"values":[0,15]},
 {"id":13,"values":[{"value":1,"name":"ClickCat"},
                    {"value":2,"name":"Banabij"},
                    {"value":3,"name":"FIN Uritus"}
                   ]
 }
]
```

Json_query, jsonarray and jsonvalue seem to bring back null. What i need is to search id7 values, id8 values etc. looking like this

```
id7 10 30 
id13 Clickcat Banabij Finuritus
```

I need the data in different columns so i can take max and min of id7 for example.

Comment: If you need to search on data in a JSON field that's a good sign that you shouldn't be using a JSON field. Normalise your database and make life easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT jsontable1.json_id, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(jsontable2.single_val, single_name) SEPARATOR ' ') json_val
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( test.val,
                       '$[*]' COLUMNS ( json_id INT PATH '$.id',
                                        json_val JSON PATH '$.values' )) jsontable1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( jsontable1.json_val,
                       '$[*]' COLUMNS ( single_val INT PATH '$',
                                        single_name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name' )) jsontable2
GROUP BY jsontable1.json_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=865a2cdfc99ee78aa3fb1e137aea5dbf

If you need in separate, not combined, values, then remove GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT. Also you may add `test.id` into the output list if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The COALESCE and JSON_TABLE functions do not seem to be working on our MySQL version. Is there an alternative way to do this? We are using MyDBR 5.9

Comment: @FelixS *MyDBR 5.9* ?? What is it? This is not DBMS.